# Fill form using table data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have a form through which I add entries to my database, I am trying to use the same form
to update/edit existing records in the database.

My page consists of a form to add data and a table which shows existing data.
the existing data table has a column **edit** against each entry, the table is filled dynamically using php.

This is what I am trying to to, when the user clicks on edit button against any row, the data in that row should be filled up into the form automatically.

I made a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZE6BX/6/)

The JS script I have tried:

```
$("#tableID").on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings().map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();

    console.log(data);
}); // the event is not recognized. no action on clicking.
```

There a quite a few techniques I found here stackoverflow, but most of them donot respond to click event or they return null/empty values, Is that because the form is filled dynamically?

I am pretty new to web development, Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Note:** *the database contains more than 20+ records (dynamically added), In Jsfiddle I have shown only 1, to keep the code clean. sorry for the lack of css styling :P*

Comment: Did you check the console for any error? In the fiddle add the jquery js to your code

Comment: Use your code within document.ready()

Comment: document.ready() detects button click thanks!!. but the data array is empty.

Comment: works fine in the fiddle.

Comment: okay! well this is what mine looks like: http://i.imgur.com/zU6eeEa.png

Comment: Yess!! It works changed bind() to on().. Thanks For The Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#tableID").on("click", ".edit_button", function() {
    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings().map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();

    console.log(data);
});
```

Use like this may be it is helpful

```
$("#tableID").click( function() {
    var data = $(this).closest("td").siblings().map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).toArray();

    console.log(data);
});
```